# React create-react-app treats tsx file as jsx(javascript) file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I know it's supposed to be simple, but it's not working and I cant figure out why..

I'm trying to migrate an existing javascript project to support some typescript files in it.
so i followed [create-react-app tutorial](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation),which says:

> run `yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`
> Next, rename any file to be a TypeScript file (e.g. src/index.js to src/index.tsx) and restart your > development server!

So i did, and rewritten `Example.jsx` to `Example.tsx`, but now i get `Parsing error: Missing semicolon` Error which probably means that create-react-app refuse to handle this file as a typescript file and to transpile it to javascript.

[image: enter]

also tried to [configure webpack manuly](https://dev.to/jacopobonta/react-typescript-webpack-3c6l?signin=true) with `ts-loader` but it seems that it doesn't work, probably because I'm using create react app.

folder structure:

```
src/
   index.jsx
   examplesFiles/
      CustomizeArrow.tsx
      ...(other jsx files)
   ...
...
```

tsconfig.json is just the default one created with create-react-app, and package.json contains all the required dependencies.

why create-react-app not transpiling the tsx file?

Comment: Did you redo a `yarn start`?

Comment: One possibility is a cached `react-scripts` package. Maybe remove the `node_modules` directory and reinstall the packages.

Comment: @jperl yes. and restarted the dev server several times.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß already tried it. does not work

Comment: That's strange... I have also used create-react-app, installed the dependencies, removed node_modules, reran yarn and then yarn start and it works.

Comment: Is that the only error you're getting? Can you use "type"?

Comment: the IDE (webstorm) recognizes typescript great, but `yarn start` throws an error as shown

Comment: How did you setup the project? Are you using a globally installed `create-react-app` module?

Comment: i used `yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
` because this is existing project as mentioned. i dont remember how this project was first made

Comment: Have you read the troubleshooting section? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the final answer, but I'll try to help anyways..

First, there is too much information mission, is there a tsconfig.json file? if not you can create one using tsc --init in your project root.

Those is my tsconfig.json for react:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

You should be able to compile single files  with `tsc myfile.tsx --jsx preserve --esModuleInterOp`.
Normally, if your app has been create with create-react-app you should be able to build or run it with your scripts: `npm run build` or `npm start` as usual